# pip : AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'Cryptography_HAS_SSL_ST'

Tags: 16.04

So everytime I want to use **pip** command on **Ubuntu 16.04** I get the following error:

```
 ~ pip3 --version              
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands.completion import CompletionCommand
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/completion.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.download import PipSession
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six, urllib3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 97, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 194, in <module>
    if _lib.Cryptography_HAS_SSL_ST:
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'Cryptography_HAS_SSL_ST'
```

I tried to reinstall **pyOpenSSL** but it requires pip to install it with the command:

```
pip install pyOpenSSL
```

which reproduces the same error message.
How can I solve this problem, please?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, running

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3-openssl
```

fixed this for me.